# can we cancel the "had"

Tags: past-perfect

> I saw my friends yesterday and they told me they were going to divorce, it was weird because I **had** seen them before and I  **had** always thought they were a happy couple. I was shocked.

Is the second *had* necessary? I think it is because  at the end of my last visit I did not think anymore  that they were a happy couple. And if I don't use past perfect the reader could understand I was shocked because I still thought  they were a happy couple .

Am I right?

Comment: It sounds a bit as repetition, although it isn't one of "had". If you feel you need to drop something, drop the second "I", making it "it was weird because I had seen them before and had always thought they were..."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need the second **had** in that sentence.

Skip the **I** too.

> **I had seen them before and always thought they were a happy couple**